# How to get current scroll height in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get current scroll height in selenium python
Such as if i have scrolled in the middle of stack overflow, so i want the current scroll height in using selenium in python
Thanks 
I have tried this

```
height =  browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question and include a [repro].

Comment: thanks, i have updated the question

Answer (score 5):

Instead try this :

```
height = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a page scroll height you can use below code

```
height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"))
```

But if you want to get the current position of scroll height, than you have to use.

```
totalScrolledHeight = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight")
```

Reference: [Selenium Scroll Current Position](https://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2021/12/python-bot-to-increase-website-traffic-using-selenium.html)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

scroll_height = element.get_attribute("scrollHeight")
```